# How to avoid empty rows after each line in dataframe?

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the column names and then write the newly named columns along with other data to a new data. Here is an example of a dataframe

```
ID      1KS     2861    2862           
TP10    0       0       0             
TP22    NA      2       2           
TP27    0       0       0             
TP33    1       0       0                
TP34    0       0       0
```

And i expected the new file to be this

```
 ID     1KS_Keizer_F_OR   2861_Lassen_NF_CA    2862_Lassen_NF_CA       
TP10    0       0       0             
TP22    NA      2       2              
TP27    0       0       0            
TP33    1       0       0                
TP34    0       0       0
```

But with my script, i am seeing an empty rows after line as below

```
ID     1KS_Keizer_F_OR   2861_Lassen_NF_CA    2862_Lassen_NF_CA       
TP10    0       0       0             

TP22    NA      2       2              

TP27    0       0       0            

TP33    1       0       0                

TP34    0       0       0
```

Here is my script..

```
import sys

result = {}

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print "python" + " " + sys.argv[0] + " " + "<rename file>" + " " + "<input file>" + " " + "<output file>"
    sys.exit()

file_in = sys.argv[1]
file_in2 = sys.argv[2]
file_out = sys.argv[3]

def main():
    fh_in = open(file_in, 'r')
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        result[line[0]] = line[1]


    with open(file_in2, 'r') as fh_in2:
        with open(file_out, 'a') as fh_out:
            for line2 in fh_in2:
                if line2.startswith("ID"):
                    line2 = line2.split()
                    for i in line2:
                        new = result[i]
                        fh_out.write(new)
                        fh_out.write("\t")

                else:
                    fh_out.write("\n")
                    fh_out.write(line2)

    fh_in.close()

main()
```

Comment: You do not strip `line2` of trailing newline.

Comment: You mean `line2 = line2.strip().split()`? It removed empty rows but i got this instead  `ID     1KS_Keizer_F_OR   2861_Lassen_NF_CA    2862_Lassen_NF_CA TP10    0       0       0 `

Comment: Yes, you should place `fh_out.write("\n")` before `else`.

Comment: Yeap it worked! Thanks @YakymPirozhenko